# Python : NameError: global name 'GetText' is not defined

Tags: python

I have been stuck with this error for a couple of hours now. Not sure what is wrong. Below is the piece of code

> NameError: global name 'GetText' is not defined

```
class BaseScreen(object):

    def GetTextFromScreen(self, x, y, a, b, noofrows = 0):
        count = 0
        message = ""        
        while (count < noofrows):
            line = Region(self.screen.x + x, self.screen.y + y + (count * 20), a, b)
            message = message + "\n" + line.text()
            count += 1            
        return message

class HomeScreen(BaseScreen):

    def GetSearchResults(self):
        if self.screen.exists("Noitemsfound.png"):
            return 'No Items Found'
        else:
            return self.GetTextFromScreen(36, 274, 680, 20, 16)

class HomeTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_001S(self):
        Home = HomeScreen()
        Home.ResetSearchCriteria()
        Home.Search("0009", "Key")
        self.assertTrue("0009" in Home.GetSearchResults(), "Key was not returned")
```

`Basescreen` class has all the reusable methods applicable across different screens.
`Homescreen` inherits `Basescreen`.
In `HomeTests` test case class, the last step is to `Home.GetSearchResults()` which in turn calls a base class method and the error.

Note:
I have another screenclass and testcaseclass doing the same which works without issues.

I have checked all the importing statements and is ok

'GetText' in the error message is the name of method initially after which i changed it to `GetTextFromScreen`

Error message is still pointing to a line 88 in code which is not there any more. Module import/reloading issue?

Comment: "Error message is still pointing to a line 88 in code which is not there any more. Module import/reloading issue?" Yes.  The point/display will show the current file, even if you haven't run it yet.  You must reload/reimport to get the new file.

Comment: Thank you. I've been using python for only about a week. Its working now. Could you please tell me why this happened and how can I avoid this in future.? Much appreciated

Comment: I have the import statement at the beginning of my script. I expected it to import everytime I run the scripts. Wasn't aware of the reload. Thanks.

Comment: If my answer helped you understand the problem, please feel free to upvote or select the answer with the checkmark.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing out your *.pyc files (or `__pycache__` if using 3+).

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> Error message is still pointing to a line 88 in code which is not there any more. Module import/reloading issue?

Yes. The traceback (error messages) will show the current (newest saved) file, even if you haven't run it yet. You must reload/reimport to get the new file.

The discrepancy comes from the fact that traceback printouts read from the script file (scriptname.py) saved on your drive.  However, the program is run either from the module saved in memory, or sometimes from the .pyc file.  If you fix an error by changing your script, and save it to your drive, then the same error will still occur if you don't reload it.

If you're running interactively for testing, you can use the `reload` function:

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> mymodule.somefunction()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mymodule.py", line 3, in somefunction
    Here is a broken line
OhNoError: Problem with your file
```

Now, you fix the error and save mymodule.py, return to your interactive session, but you still get the error, but the traceback shows the fixed line

```
>>> mymodule.somefunction()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mymodule.py", line 3, in somefunction
    Here is the fixed line
OhNoError: Problem with your file
```

So you have to reload the module:

```
>>> reload(mymodule)
<module 'mymodule' from '/path/to/mymodule.py'>
>>> mymodule.somefunction()
Success!
```